# When to use client-side or server-side?

Tags: client-side, server-side

I just finished an intro to web dev course in my CS program and came away wondering something simple. When should you use JavaScript (client-side) instead of server-side (we used PHP but anything applies) code? Vice-versa as well.

Comment: Regarding Parse.com .... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24010828/294884

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no recipe for deciding that. A few notes:

- security and validation should always be present at the server side (sometimes duplicated in the client).
- the client-side should contain only UI-logic. No business logic.
- logically, everything that accesses a database should be on the server.

Of course, if your application is a RIA (rich internet app), then you can have logic on the client. So it all depends.

Comment: Would an example of your first point be having one of those little graphics that says your input is valid, but then double-checking on the server before accepting?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript should be only used to manipulate the UI of the page. You can also do certain validations using it, however, there must be corresponding validation on the server-side. For doing any data manipulation, applying business logic, etc you should always use server side code.

Here are some cases where you will use client-side code:

- Changing the look (UI) of the page e.g. dynamically show/hide some
  elements
- Validate user inputs (this should also be done on server side)

Cases where to use server-side code:

- Validation of user inputs (should always be done on server side irrespective of whether done on client side or not.)
- User authentication
- Business logic (deciding what to show to which users, calculations)
- Database access

Answer (score 1):

Imho i would say, use server-side if you can. All client-side code can be manipulated. Or maybe will not run cause the browser dont support it.