# How to make this Parse.com cloud code call?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift

Note:

Here's some thoughts from CA at Parse about this:

https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-when-will-swift-for-parse-be-ready

(notice how popular that question is - hot topic).  Hope it helps someone

---

Here's an iOS7 Parse cloud code call ...

how to do this in SWIFT ?  cheers

To be clear ... **can you use "callFunctionInBackground" in SWIFT**, or do you have to just call to an objc class?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    int thisRow = indexPath.row;
    PFUser *delFriend = [self.theFriends objectAtIndex:thisRow];

    NSLog(@"you wish to delete .. %@", [delFriend fullName] );

    // note, this cloud call is happily is set and forget
    // there's no return either way. life's like that sometimes

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"clientRequestFriendRemove"
            withParameters:@{
                            @"removeThisFriendId":delFriend.objectId
                            }
            block:^(NSString *serverResult, NSError *error)
            {
            if (!error)
                {
                NSLog(@"ok, Return (string) %@", serverResult);
                }
            }];

    [self back];    // that simple
    }
```

---

Note, I've noticed this is a google landing page for trying to figure out "how the heck to do cloud code calls" (unrelated to Swift).  Here is a full, complete set of **example code for both iOS and Android** of custom cloud code functions, in the Parse.com universe https://stackoverflow.com/a/24010828/294884  Hope it helps someone

Comment: later - full example code http://stackoverflow.com/a/24261024/294884

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an Objective-C .m file to your project.  Xcode will ask about creating a Bridge Header file.  Say yes.

Delete the .m file.  In the bridge header file, add your import statement:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Another answer, which has a way better walkthrough than mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/353988

Now you can call native Parse code in Swift, i.e.:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    Parse.setApplicationId("appid", clientKey: "clientkey")
    var obj = PFObject(className:"TestObject")
    obj.setObject("bar", forKey: "foo")
    obj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock ({ 
      (succeeded: Bool!, err: NSError!) -> Void in
      NSLog("Hi")
    })

  }

}
```

Comment: A perfect explanation! SO brilliance!  I guess "callFunctionInBackground" or any other Parse call would work the same.

Comment: Yep, just have to find the right syntax for the returning block.

Comment: Awesome and just some more info from Awesome Parse Krew .. https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-when-will-swift-for-parse-be-ready

Comment: Added an opening bracket following saveInBackgroundWithBlock

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to call this exact function (**callFunctionInBackground**) because it is an obj-C function.

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) how to call obj-c functions.

With time Parse will also introduce Swift implementation.

Comment: Ahhhh ..you're saying it's **not possible** to call to callFunctionInBackground in SWIFT .. do I understand you Vive?  Cheers...

Comment: It is not possible to call this exact function because it is obj-C function ;). However you can import obj-C class to your Swift code and implement Swift method to work in the background basing on [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75). Alternatively you can write this in obj-C, as you have, then import it to your Swift code, but 1st method seems better.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong.  It's easy to access Objective-C libraries in Swift projects.

Comment: @Fosco I don't claim anything else. I've said that you have to import Objective-C and implement a method where you use Objevtive-C code from that imported file. Also I've attached a link, where you have exact explanation how to access Obj-C methods in Swift so I don't understand your vote down.

Comment: The link is definitely awesome, but it's preceded by 'not possible' and followed by 'with time'.