# parse.com cloud code returns {"result":"success"} instead of value

Tags: python, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm calling cloud code function from Python.
In the Cloud Code I'm returning the value using a call like

```
response.success(game.id);
```

Everything seems to work except that my Python client code is not able to get the result

```
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)

connection.request(...

response = connection.getresponse()
print response.status
print response.read()
```

I'm getting:

```
200
{"result":"success"}
```

How can I extract the value returned by Cloud Code function?

Comment: Just FWIW, [Here's a Parse.com cloud code custom call example, and exactly how to call it from both iOS and Android...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24010828/294884)

Comment: Also [useful](https://www.parse.com/questions/custom-error-response-codes-for-cloud-code)

Answer (score 0):

The `response.read` indicates that the cloud code function is not returning anything. On the other hand it has done what it was suppose to do with success.